# AVD native Google Maps app shows only the controls and a black screen in the background (the map is totally black)

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, screen, android-virtual-device

I'm having a problem with my AVD, when I tap the native Maps app in the AVD it shows me a black screen, I only see the controls.

I spent some time here searching something similar and there are lots of questions similar, but all is about an app being developed. I'm one step before, I'm wanting to create an app that will use map, but if the native Google Maps app doesn't work, how to make my works.

I'm running the Nexus S device with Google API Level 19 and my OS is Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

**Update**
I got more info from the log cat when I start the native Google Maps app like below:

```
04-12 14:26:12.330: E/libEGL(51): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
04-12 14:26:12.340: E/SurfaceFlinger(51): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -1604787273
04-12 14:26:12.340: E/SurfaceFlinger(51): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
04-12 14:26:12.340: W/WindowManager(381): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005
04-12 14:26:14.840: E/libEGL(2896): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

Comment: are you using real device or virtual device for testing??

Comment: I'm using a virtual device.